# How to fetch remote table ids through an association table with Doctrine2 DQL

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, dql

I have the following model with 2 tables `foo` and `bar` and the `foo_has_bar` association in between:

[image]

I'm trying to get, for a given `foo.id`, all the corresponding `bar.id`'s.

So far I have been able to retrieve all the entries from `foo_has_bar` related to a particular `foo.id` as follows:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT h FROM 'FooHasBar' h INNER JOIN h.foo f WHERE f.id = ?1");
$query->setParameter(1, $foo_id);
$results = $query->getArrayResult();
```

The problem is that `$results` only contains the `id` field for `foo_has_bar`, not the foreign keys `foo_id` and `bar_id`, and therefore I can't achieve what I want.

**Is there a way, given a particular `foo.id` to retrieve all the corresponding `bar.id`'s with a single DQL command?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the entity `FooHasBar` has a relation `foo` and a relation `bar` respectively to `Foo` and `Bar`, the query is quite trivial:

```
$q = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT 
        b.id as bar_id, f.id as foo_id 
    FROM FooHasBar fb 
    JOIN fb.bar b 
    JOIN fb.foo f 
    WHERE f.id = :fooId'
);
$q->setParameter( 'fooId', $foo->getId() );

$results = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the association between the entities is bidirectional:

```
$q = $em->createQuery( 'SELECT b.id FROM Bar b JOIN b.fooHasBar x WHERE x.foo = :fooId' );
$q->setParameter( 'fooId', $foo->getId() );

$results = $query->getScalarResult();
```

If the association between the entities is unidirectional (this only works in Doctrine 2.3+):

```
$q = $em->createQuery( 'SELECT b.id FROM Bar b JOIN FooHasBar x WITH x.bar = b.id WHERE x.foo = :fooId' );
$q->setParameter( 'fooId', $foo->getId() );

$results = $query->getScalarResult();
```

Comment: Thanks but they both fail for me. The first fails with `Class Bar has no association named fooHasBar` which I think refers to `JOIN b.fooHasBar` whereas the second fails with `Identification Variable FooHasBar used in join path expression but was not defined before` which I think refers to `JOIN FooHasBar x`. Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: @Jasper he doesn't have a `ManyToMany` association in there... That was confusing from the question btw.

Comment: I assumed there are ManyToOne/OneToMany associations in place, and that the entities/properties are named like the the tables/columns are (camelcased). @user359650: Maybe you could provide (the relevant parts of) your entity code?

Comment: Thanks `Jasper` but it won't be necessary since I got what I was looking for from `Ocramius`'s answer.